# One To Many Relationship Group Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Seriously, I don't know how to express this correctly.

I have 2 models:

```
    public class ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProfesorId { get; set; }
    public int CursoId { get; set; }
    public int MateriaId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Referencia a la columna de Grupo en GrupoPeriodo
    /// </summary>
    public int Grupo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProfesorId")]
    public virtual Profesor Profesor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Grupo")]
    public virtual List<GrupoPeriodo> GrupoPeriodo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CursoId")]
    public virtual Curso Curso { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MateriaId")]
    public virtual Materia Materia { get; set; }
}



public class GrupoPeriodo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PeriodoId { get; set; }
        public int Grupo { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PeriodoId")]
        public virtual Periodo Periodo { get; set; }

    }
```

I want from `ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo` to use the `Grupo` property to fetch all the values from `GrupoPeriodo` which contain the same values as the `Grupo` column from the latter (`GrupoPeriodo`).

Example:

```
   var grupoPeriodo = new GrupoPeriodo[]
    {
        new GrupoPeriodo
        {
            Id = 1,
            PeriodoId = 1,
            Grupo = 1,

        },
        new GrupoPeriodo
        {
            Id = 2,
            PeriodoId = 2,
            Grupo = 1,
        },
        new GrupoPeriodo
        {
            Id = 3,
            PeriodoId = 3,
            Grupo = 1,
        },
        new GrupoPeriodo
        {
            Id = 4,
            PeriodoId = 4,
            Grupo = 1,

        },
    };
```

I want that, when I have:

```
new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 1, CursoId = 1, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 1,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 2, CursoId = 2, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 1,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 3, CursoId = 3, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 1,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 4, CursoId = 4, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 1,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 5, CursoId = 5, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 1,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 6, CursoId = 6, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 1,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 7, CursoId = 7, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 1,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 8, CursoId = 1, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 2,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 9, CursoId = 2, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 2,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 10, CursoId = 3, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 2,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 11, CursoId = 4, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 2,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 12, CursoId = 5, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 2,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 13, CursoId = 6, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 2,  ProfesorId = 1},
                new ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodo {Id = 14, CursoId = 7, Grupo = 1, MateriaId = 2,  ProfesorId = 1},
```

All of the above point to the same "Group" of `GrupoPeriodo`.

Is this even possible? I want to do this without explicitly defining a foreign key of the form `ProfesorCursoMateriaPeriodoId` in `GrupoPeriodo`.

Comment: Let me clarify - you want to create FK reference to table column which is not PK and not unique?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev. Yes.(I want to avoid making a separate DB call).

Comment: It's not possible in relational databases, hence in EF Core. You need to use manual join queries. Btw, the number of db calls depends only on the type of the query. The relationships and navigation properties just allow writing more readable queries with automatic joins.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Awesome!!! I'll consider this case closed, then :) Thank you so much for all the help!!